# Need a particular mathematical function to standardise animation duration

Tags: reactjs, animation, math, framer-motion

I am using framer-motion (React) to animate a slider containing 100 slides. The animation simply moves the slides to the left relative to the viewport so that the target slide is directly in the middle and focussed. The target slide in question is determined dynamically, so the issue I'm having is that with a hard-coded animation duration (3s), it looks very jerky and fast if the target slide is slide 100, and very slow if it is slide 3, for example.

What I'm looking for is a formula which will take my target slide (1-100) and make it tend towards an ideal animation duration, let's say 3s. So if it animates from slide 1 to slide 3, it might take 1 second, but if it animates from slide 1 to 100 it might take something like 5 seconds.

I'm sure this can be accomplished elegantly but I'm not the greatest at maths. Perhaps a reciprocal function? I have tried simply setting breakpoints (e.g. if target is <10 away, set duration to 1s; else if target is <20 away, set duration to 2s etc...) but I would like to solve this with less code.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than simply providing you with the formula, I want to push against your *"I'm not greatest at maths"* a bit. I'll take you through the logical steps of figuring out the formula and show you that once you know how to take it apart, it's no longer magic, but doable.

---

Let's say we want the animation across 100 slides to take `5s` and the animation between adjacent slides to take `1s`.

This means each animation takes `1s` plus some extra time, based on additional slides travelled.
We put the second aside for now (we'll add it back in the end) and look for a relation between extra slides travelled and extra time added. We have `0s` extra time without any additional slide and `4s` with 99 additional slides, which gives us:

| additional slides travelled | extra time (s) | total time (s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 99 | 4 | 5 |
| x | x * 4/99 | 1 + (x * 4/99) |

The formula is determined with [rule of three](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RuleofThree.html#:%7E:text=The%20so%2Dcalled%20rule%20of,One%20direct%20and%20one%20inverse.) (`x * 4 = 99 * y`), as the relation between additional slides travelled and extra time is one of direct proportionality. ***<sup>1</sup>***

As a function, the above total time formula is: `x => 1 + x * 4/99`, where:

- `1` is `minDuration`
- `x` is the number of additional slides traveled, so it's `indexesDiff - 1`
- `4` is `maxDuration - minDuration`
- `99` is `totalSlides - 1`,

Which gives us:

```js
const [minDuration, maxDuration, totalSlides] = [1, 5, 100]
const getDuration = (distance = 1) =>
  minDuration +
  ((distance - 1) * (maxDuration - minDuration)) / (totalSlides - 1)
```

...where `distance` is the difference of indexes between start and end slides of animation.

Let's see it in action:

```js
const { computed, reactive, createApp } = Vue
const [min, max, total] = [1, 5, 100]
const state = reactive({
  distance: 1,
  total,
  d: computed(() => min + ((max - min) * (state.distance - 1)) / (total - 1)),
  duration: computed(() => (Math.round(state.d * 1e3) / 1e3).toFixed(3))
})

createApp({
  setup: () => state
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: monospace
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.3.9/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label>
    distance:
    <input
      type="range"
      min="1"
      :max="total"
      v-model.number="distance"
    />
  </label>
  {{ distance }} slide{{ distance === 1 ? '' : 's' }}
  <div>duration: {{ duration }}s</div>
</div>
```

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - In other words, we divide the max extra time into as many parts as there are max extra slides and, for each extra slide we add an equal amount of time.